# How to remove all lines in a file containing a specific character except for the first?

Tags: python, line

I am trying to make a script that merges all files in a directory and then remove unwanted lines in the output file. The lines I want to remove contain the same string pattern and I want to remove all but the first of those lines (which is also the first line in the file). Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
import glob

# Merge all output files into one file
read_files = glob.glob('/home/user/Results/Script_tests/TestResults/*.output')

with open('MergedOutput.txt', 'r+b') as outfile:
    for file in read_files:
        with open(file, 'r+b') as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())

print 'Files merged.'          

# Remove header rows except from row 1

final_output = open('FinalMergedOutput.txt', 'r+b')
with open('MergedOutput.txt', 'r+b') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line == 0 and line.startswith('File'):
            final_output.write(line)
        elif line > 0 and not line.startswith('File'):
             final_output.write(line) 

print 'Headers removed except on line 1.'
```

The merging part works pretty well except for that some lines seem to be copied in `FinalMergedOutput.txt`. The removal of lines however removes ALL lines starting with `File` and does not spare the first...

Does anyone have an elegant solution to this?

Comment: use a `flag=0` and increment it on first instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for line in file` iterates over the actual content of the file, not line numbers. Since even the empty string is greater than 0, your first condition can never  e true and the 2nd one always is (when `.startswith(..)` is also true...).

There are many idioms of to for special handling of the first item in a list, This is a pretty straight forward one with minimal adjustments to your code:

```
for line_num,line in enumerate(file):
    if line_num == 0 and line.startswith('File'):
        final_output.write(line)
    elif line_num > 0 and not line.startswith('File'):
         final_output.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

`line == 0` will not work. `line` is a string containing the text of that line, so it will never be zero. Instead, keep tracking of the *line number*, for example using `enumerate`:

```
for lineNumber, line in enumerate(file):
    if lineNumber == 0 and line.startswith('File'):
        final_output.write(line)
    elif lineNumber > 0 and not line.startswith('File'):
        final_output.write(line)
```

You can also simplify that check:

```
for lineNumber, line in enumerate(file):
    if lineNumber == 0 or not line.startswith('File'):
        final_output.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, open the file:

```
f = open("yourfile.txt","r")
```

Next, get all your lines from the file:

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

Now you can close the file:

```
f.close()
```

And reopen it in write mode:

```
f = open("yourfile.txt","w")
```

Then, write your lines back, except the line you want to delete. You might want to change the "\n" to whatever line ending your file uses.

```
for line in lines:
  if line!="file_line_to_delete"+"\n":
    f.write(line)
```

At the end, close the file again.

```
f.close()
```

You can append file one by one. Learn **Python Pandas library**.